# Keep image ratio on load + on resize, while behaving like "object-fit:cover" when rendered onto a canvas

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create an image distortion slider, using images that will act as backgrounds while the links are in the foreground. When you hover each link the background image distorts into the next image according to the link hovered

I am having trouble figuring out why the images rendered onto the canvas is stretched/skewed on every page load on various screen sizes?

Want to see what in the three.js formula/code is causing this issue

I've linked the [Codepen to this issue](https://codepen.io/vchoo/pen/OJGMXaZ)

Here's the formula for the canvas width/height as well as rendered width/height that I got so far:

```
let canvasWidth = images[0].clientWidth;
let canvasHeight = images[0].clientHeight;

let renderWidth = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
let renderHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);

let renderW, renderH;

    if( renderWidth > canvasWidth ) {
        renderW = renderWidth;
    } else {
        renderW = canvasWidth;
    }

    renderH = canvasHeight;

renderer.setSize( renderW, renderH );

let aspectRatioCanvas = renderWidth / renderHeight;
let aspectRatio = images[0].clientWidth / images[0].clientHeight;

let scaleWidth = 1;
    let scaleHeight = 1;

    if (aspectRatio > aspectRatioCanvas) {
        scaleWidth = aspectRatio / aspectRatioCanvas;
    } else {
        scaleHeight = aspectRatioCanvas / aspectRatio;
    }

    let geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(
        renderWidth * scaleWidth,
        renderHeight * scaleHeight,
        1
    );
```

Followed by the resize event:

```
window.addEventListener( 'resize' , function(e) {
        renderWidth = parent.offsetWidth;
        renderHeight = parent.offsetHeight;
        renderer.setSize(renderWidth, renderHeight);

        let newAspectRatioCanvas = renderWidth / renderHeight;
        let newScaleWidth = 1;
        let newScaleHeight = 1;

        if (aspectRatio > newAspectRatioCanvas) {
            newScaleWidth = aspectRatio / newAspectRatioCanvas;
        } else {
            newScaleHeight = newAspectRatioCanvas / aspectRatio;
        }

        object.scale.set(newScaleWidth, newScaleHeight, 1);
});
```

Thanks so much in advance

I want to have the image behave like background images (with object-fit:cover or background-size:cover) while keeping aspect ratio when rendered onto the canvas

Edit 3/11/2024: Codepen (https://codepen.io/vchoo/pen/OJGMXaZ) is updated where the background images are covering the canvas while keeping aspect ratio, but the images are not centered to the canvas.

Have tried editing the vertex shader, the ShaderMaterial function, but nothing's working so far..

Comment: This should help you: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/17199

Comment: @WestLangley hi thank you for the reference api, i'm really new to three.js so forgive me for not understanding how to integrate the linked solution.

Do I need to modify the fragment shader according to the formula outlined here? https://github.com/WestLangley/three.js/blob/a87dd8c261f37c3595798beebc7c2aed59f0721f/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib/background_frag.glsl.js

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s0azkxq9/show implements the technique I referenced in my comment above. It shows how to emulate the CSS 'cover' behavior in the three.js `scene.background`. Perhaps this example will be helpful to you in your application.... Also, your example is using a version of three.js from 2016. I suggest you use the current three.js version, instead.

Comment: @WestLangley Thank you for the example! Will this work with Orthographic Camera? I use that currently in my application; or should I change to Perspective Camera?